# Java Calendar: What exactly does the field DATE, DATE_OF_YEAR contain?

Tags: java, calendar

I have a code snipplet like this:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(c.DATE);
    System.out.println(c.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

And the output is:

```
    5
    6
    Wed Oct 09
```

I'm not exactly sure why printing `c.DATE` and `c.DAY_OF_YEAR` gives me `5` and `6`

The date is `Wed Oct 09` so I was expecting `c.DATE` to be `9`, and `c.DAY_OF_YEAR` to be `282`

Explanations would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: They are **constants**; you want `System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE));` - or **better** use the `java.time` classes instead (`Calendar` is notoriously difficult to use).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Many have been confused before you. Instead use for example `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime`. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are actually flags for the calendar class to fetch a specific part of a calendar date. (yes, it is ugly)

To get the value of a specific part of the calendar, you need to use its `.get()` method. This method accepts an integer flag of the field you want to get.

```
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Will have the same results as:

```
System.out.println(c.get(5));
System.out.println(c.get(6));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Comment: For the usage: The word *flag* is not usually used in this sense. [What is a flag in programming?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-flag-in-programming) Otherwise the explanation is correct (and I still discourage the use of the `Calendar` class altogether, but I am repeating myself).